# True crypt - input form is too short

Tags: truecrypt

I have a file that contains an encrypted [TrueCrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt) volume, along with the password.

It is a few year old now, and I wish to decrypt it.

The problem is that I downloaded truecrypt on both osx and Ubuntu, and the input password prompt will stop accepting new characters after reaching a certain length (about 125 char). Now my password is much longer than that.

How can I decrypt this volume ? For instance, is there a CLI option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a command line option in OSX. You can see the full list [here](http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2011/10/17/easy-access-to-truecrypt-from-the-command-line-in-os-x/). I can't answer your question directly (I can't seem to locate an actual spec on password length) so you'll need to try your long password with the CLI. Good luck!